Website audit error: "Confirmation (return) links missing on hreflang pages" despite hreflang being implemented in WordPress
I'm facing an issue with my website audit where I'm receiving an error: "Confirmation (return) links missing on hreflang pages."
My website is built using WordPress and is multilingual. I'm using Polylang and YoastSEO to manage languages, and these plugins automatically generate the hreflang tags for each language version of a page.
Here is an example of how the hreflang tags are structured on all language versions of the same page:
<link rel="alternate" href="https://websitename.se/" hreflang="sv" /> 
<link rel="alternate" href="https://websitename.de/" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://websitename.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://websitename.no/" hreflang="nb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://websitename.dk/" hreflang="da" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://websitename.fi/" hreflang="fi" />

Each version of the page backlinks to all other versions, so I'm not sure why the audit is flagging this as an issue. I assumed that the hreflang setup was correct, given that the tags exist for each language.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem or knows how to resolve this? Is there something I might be missing with the hreflang implementation?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried disabling the automatic hreflang generation from the plugins and manually implementing the hreflang tags directly in the header. I expected this to resolve the issue and remove the audit error. However, the error still persists, even with manual implementation.

Welcome! This could be a false positive and nothing to do on your end, or there may be some pages that are missing translations. Check some manually. If everything looks correct.
